# Can anyone tell me why do I get this error in logcat?

Tags: android, android-logcat

I'm a Newbie in Android.Please tell me what does the following log cat error mean and how do I get rid of it? In my app what I'm doing is blocking unwanted calls.When I'm pressing backbutton while using my app, I'm getting this error. Please help

```
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265): Activity com.deepthi.blockmycalls.BlockMyCallsActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.deepthi.blockmycalls.BlockMyCallsActivity$1@44f03d18 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.deepthi.blockmycalls.BlockMyCallsActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.deepthi.blockmycalls.BlockMyCallsActivity$1@44f03d18 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(ActivityThread.java:939)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.getReceiverDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:734)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:791)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:778)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:772)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:318)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at com.deepthi.blockmycalls.BlockMyCallsActivity.onCheckedChanged(BlockMyCallsActivity.java:155)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:124)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:86)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:98)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265): Activity com.deepthi.blockmycalls.BlockMyCallsActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.deepthi.blockmycalls.BlockMyCallsActivity$1@44efa3a8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.deepthi.blockmycalls.BlockMyCallsActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.deepthi.blockmycalls.BlockMyCallsActivity$1@44efa3a8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(ActivityThread.java:939)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.getReceiverDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:734)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:791)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:778)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:772)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:318)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at com.deepthi.blockmycalls.BlockMyCallsActivity.onCheckedChanged(BlockMyCallsActivity.java:155)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:124)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:86)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:98)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-18 16:59:55.812: D/dalvikvm(3265): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4770 objects / 267120 bytes in 592ms
```

My Code:

```
  @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         CallBlocker =new BroadcastReceiver()
         {
           @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                Bundle extra=intent.getExtras();//new
                telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                if(extra!=null)//new=== getting the blocked number
                {
                     state=extra.getString(telephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

                    if(state.equals(telephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
                    {
                        number=extra.getString(telephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                        Log.w("NUMBER",number);
                    }
                }
                Class c = null;
                try {
                        c = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
               Method m = null;
                try {
                        m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        m.setAccessible(true);
        try {
            telephonyService = (ITelephony)m.invoke(telephonyManager);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        telephonyManager.listen(new MyPhoneStateListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }//onReceive()

         class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
            {
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
                {

                    switch (state)
                    {
                        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                           if (true) // if incomingNumber need to be blocked
                           {
                               if(Enable_chkbox.isChecked())
                               {
                                try {
                                 end_call=telephonyService.endCall();
                                 if(end_call==true)
                                 {                          
                                     android.telephony.SmsManager sms = android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault();
                                     sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, SMS, null, null);
                                 }
                                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                   }//try catch
                             }//if chkbox enabled
                           }
                           break;
                        default:
                           break;
                     }
                  }
                }

            };//Broadcast receiver
            IntentFilter filter= new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
            registerReceiver(CallBlocker, filter);

    }
```

Unregistering in:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(CallBlocker);
    this.finish();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Everything is working fine unless I press the back button..

Comment: you had register receiver but i think you forgot to un-register that receiver.. Please un-register that...

Comment: I've unregistered my receiver already..

Comment: @user1362681 - Just a style point - in Java, always start variables with a lowercase letter. Capitalized names are usually reserved for types.

Comment: Here's the problem, `onDestroy()` will only be called if you `finish()` your activity.  Without knowing your design, `onPause()` or `onStop()` might be better choices.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show your code so this is a guess.

The clue is here:

05-18 16:58:32.614: E/ActivityThread(3265): Activity com.deepthi.blockmycalls.BlockMyCallsActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.deepthi.blockmycalls.BlockMyCallsActivity$1@44efa3a8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

Are you unregistering your receiver when your activity finishes?

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){

    super.onPause();

    if (myMessageReceiver != null){
        unregisterReceiver(myMessageReceiver );
        myMessageReceiver = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you have a resource that you dont release/unregister
Need more code to be specific

Comment: Metnik: thanks for the response. I just noticed that your answer is voted down by someone. So an upvote from me as its a relevant guess anyways didn't help me. I've already updated my question with my code. please help :(

Comment: I think i'd do something complete different in your case.
I dont, maybe it's just me, see the reason why you are doing your broadcasters in code.
It's a lot more safe and easier, to add them in xml. Which android also tells you is best.

Answer (score 0):

If you can post your code, maybe will be easier to help you, but it seems you're registrering your receiver twice.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm only registering it once. I've already updated my question with the code..

Comment: @user1362681 I still think your registering twice before unregistering. Maybe when you push back button OnCheckedChange is call once again. Try to put a breakpoint and debug the app.

Comment: @gutiory added vote up because i think it is a shame when someone comes in and votes us down, when we try to explain without seeing code. As also happened to me.

Comment: @AndersMetnik thanks. I just wanted to help. Anyway, did you get any solution?.

Comment: @guitiory: No still I'm facing the issue.. :(